# Ionic Modal displays only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having a simple modal to be displayed while the data is being fetched from an API call. as I trigger the loading once, the modal gets displayed and the data will be loaded but upon second time click on loading button, the modal won't load anymore.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('views/loading.html', {
   scope: $scope,
   backdropClickToClose: false,
   hardwareBackButtonClose: true,
   animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
  $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.openModal = function() {
   $scope.modal.show();
   alertServices.getInvoices()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.closeModal();
    })
}

$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
};

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $scope.modal.remove();
});
```

This is the reload button triggering the modal to be displayed:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
   <button class="button button-icon ion-android-refresh" ng-click="openModal()">
   </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

This is the function with API calls:

```
function getInvoices() {

    var urlDaily =  sharedProperties.Api + 
                "/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices?" +
                "$select=OrderNumber,InvoiceToName,AmountDC&"

    var urlWeekly = sharedProperties.Api + 
                "/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices?" +
                "$select=OrderNumber,InvoiceToName,AmountDC&";

    var promiseDaily = $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDaily, cache: 'true'});
    var promiseWeekly = $http({method: 'GET', url: urlWeekly, cache: 'true'});

    var promises = $q.all([promiseDaily, promiseWeekly, promiseMonthly]).then(function(data){
                        setData(data[0].data, 'SalesInvoice', 'Daily');
                        setData(data[1].data, 'SalesInvoice', 'Weekly');
                    });
    return promises;
}

function setData(data, alert, type){
    var invoicesList = data.d.results;
    $localstorage.setObject('Setting' + alert + type, invoicesList);
}
```

Comment: but you close modal when `getInvoices` success: `$scope.closeModal();`

Comment: yes and still, the user sould be able to get the (latest) data but clicking on button that opens the modal and calls the API again. which fails to do so.

Comment: do you see any erros in browser console? can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: the odd part is I don't get any error in console. I just added the function for API calls to the post as well. I will try to make the plunkr

Comment: can you provide also what do `setData` function?

Comment: i see you set `cache: 'true'` are you sure that do request on second click? probably it just quick get value from cache, and fast close modal

Comment: ok added that one too,

Comment: cache: 'false' would have the same result as well. just tested it again. but indeed when I add the log in the console I can see that the requests are not done the second round. even without the cache: 'true'. but why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95169/discussion-between-grundy-and-afflatus).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @grundy
I have changed two lines in the function that makes API calls and now it works:
1- empty the promises before reassigning the http calls to it.
2- remove the caching from http calls:

```
var promiseDaily = $http({method: 'GET', url: urlDaily, cache: false});
```

and what was important was that `cache: 'false'` was noy correct. it was not working even though no error was logged in console because of it.